# How nexttuple and excute be called in storm framework

Tags: task, apache-storm

I think each task will contain an instance of spout or bolt, and a while or for block calls them, is it right?

If so, since every task coordinates to one of some threads running in a worker process, and there is probability that two or more tasks of the same spout or bolt are assigned to the same worker, in this case, do we need to sync (especially if the spout or bolt contains critical resources such as static members)? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, several tasks of the same spout/bolt could be assigned to the same worker and run in the same JVM. I recommend not to use static members that are not thread-safe - in this case you won't to need care about synchronization.